# ifconfig won't let me set MAC address that doesn't begin with 00:26

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, mac-address, ifconfig

I have an Intel 1000 BGN Wi-Fi card and I tried to set its MAC address to **00:00:de:ad:be:ef**, but this didn't work:

```
[root@localhost .]# ifconfig wlan0 hw ether 00:00:de:ad:be:ef
SIOCSIFHWADDR: Cannot assign requested address
```

But setting it to **00:26:de:ad:be:ef** worked. Do you know where the problem is?

On Windows I wasn't able even to change the MAC address; it just didn't change when I changed registry entries, etc.

Comment: What is the original mac address of the adapter?

Comment: 00:26:03:xx:xx:xx <-- in every Intel Wifi card it starts with 00:26...

Comment: Also, I've read about that you cannot change to MAC that doesn't start with 00:26, but I thought it is on Windows.

Comment: Every "normal" LAN or WLAN driver can change the whole src-address, this looks like a restriction. You should be able to find the location of the 00 26 with a hex editor. Make a copy of the driver and change it.